# Submiting Open Graph Read action

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

Facebook keeps rejecting my read action each time I submit it.
Please note that my open graph application functionality includes the deletion of an article as that is required by facebook.

you can visit my website at www.heyngine.com

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the `Read` action on your website, you must use the build-in `read` action (`news.reads`) and not create your own action for the same thing. Facebook will reject your action if its a duplicate of a build-in action.

Secondly, when you login to Facebook via your site, it doesn't ask for the `publish_action` permission. This is required to publish actions to Facebook. Without this, your `read` action will not get published to the user's profile. Also, why are the 'Social On/Off' and 'Delete' buttons visible when I'm not logged into your website via Facebook?

Facebook Documentation / Policy says the user must have a separate 'logged in' experience to logged out users. I.e. Facebook Users should only see 'Social On/Off' and 'Delete' once they have connected to your site via Facebook, not before as you do currently.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am using the build in Read action but I think I have to submit it... I am not sure about that, I have to check it. I have made the change you recommended on the website.

Comment: You will be able to see your read action as long as you are logged in as the developer / admin / tester of the app. Everyone will be able to see it once it's approved. You should be able to see if the read action works straight away.

Comment: The Read action is working just fine on my test account. Just waiting for the approval. thnx